# How can we extract name using spacy nlp in rasa?

Tags: nlp, spacy, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I tried what is found in the document and also put the spacynlp and the dimension I want which is *PERSON* but still rasa wont extract the name for me using spacynlp ..is there another way we can use spacynlp for extracting a person name ..please I need some help on how to extract name in rasa using spacynlp

Answer (score 0):

I tried on a similar thing. In my case, I want to extract all the proper nouns from the input. SpacyNlp didn't help me much. You can try testing your examples in this [interactive demo](https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy-ent).

Another way which I tried out is to generate some random alphabetical strings out of regex. Use those strings as examples in training data and mark them as "Person" entity. Make sure you have enough examples for entities so that Entity extractor can recognise any random alpha string as an "Person" entity.